# Delphi modal login form not restoring after minimizing

Tags: forms, delphi, modal-dialog, restore, minimize

I have created a Delphi 2010 application which displays a modal login form via a function before the Application.Initialize. The login form is NOT my main form. This is my login form's code:

```
unit frmLogin_u;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmLogin = class(TForm)
    edtPass: TEdit;
    btnLogin: TButton;
    procedure btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    class function Execute: Boolean;
  end;

var
  frmLogin: TfrmLogin;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm2 }

procedure TfrmLogin.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if edtPass.Text = 'Delphi' then
    ModalResult :=  mrOk
  else
    MessageDlg('Incorrect password.', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
end;

class function TfrmLogin.Execute: Boolean;
begin
  with TfrmLogin.Create(nil) do
  try
    Result := ShowModal = mrOk;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

And here's my application's source code:

```
program frmLogin_p;

uses
  Forms,
  frmMain_u in 'frmMain_u.pas' {frmMain},
  frmLogin_u in 'frmLogin_u.pas' {frmLogin};

{$R *.res}

begin
  if TfrmLogin.Execute then
  begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
    Application.Run;
  end;
end.
```

Here's my problem: when the login form is shown, even though its border style is set to bsDialog, when the form gets minimized via clicking on its taskbar icon, I can't seem to restore it after clicking on the taskbar icon again. So now I need to close the application via the Task Manager and reopen it for I have no way to restore or close it while it is minimized.

Does anyone maybe know why this is happening and what I can do to resolve the issue?

Comment: VCL forms rely on Application being already initialized. Try something like this: let application initialize, create main form (hidden), show your login dialog, if successful show the main form, otherwise quit.

Comment: expanding on @TOndrej's advice: use the FormCreate event and put your login logic there...

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply guys. I let the program initialize and tried a few options:
1. Putting everything after the initialization in a if block. This removes the icon from the taskbar and prevents minimizing through it. Only problem now is that the user can still minimize all open windows via Windows Key + D or clicking in the lower right corner of the screen.

Comment: Why do you want to stop the user seeing their desktop?

Comment: Application.Initialize does little more than call the init procs which just inits com if memory serves.

Comment: 2. I allowed the main form to be created and hid it. I executed my function via its FormCreate event handler like you said. The results are the same as above. There is no taskbar icon but the modal form can still be minimized.

Comment: I don't want to prevent the user from seeing the desktop, I just want to restore my login window if it somehow became minimized.

Comment: This issue doesn't seem to affect D7. Either way, there's an icon in the taskbar and I can both minimize and restore the login form using it. I'm using Windows 7, btw.

Comment: You keep talking about blocking minimising. Is that the problem? Or do you want to be able to restore the login form.

Comment: I am using Delphi 2010 and yes David, I can't restore it after it has been minimized.

Comment: So is that what you want? To be able to restore? Do you mind about the minimising or hiding?

Comment: `Application` is initialized *on* the `begin` line of the project source, in initialization section of controls.pas. `Application.Initialize` just, by default, initializes COM. The only thing the first comments could make a difference on is the `MainFormOnTaskBar` line, is it before or after you show your modal form.

Answer (score 0):

if you do it this way:

```
program Project2;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  if TForm2.Execute then
  begin
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Application.Run;
  end;
end.
```

do not show the icon in the taskbar.
I don't know if it solve your problem.